# SQL equal operator implicit conversion?

Tags: sql

```
select count(ID)
from student
where dept_name = (select dept_name
                   from instructor
                   where ID = '14364'
                  );
```

I know that select operator return a relation. However, dept_name should equal a value(varchar).
So, why this query works?
Implicit conversion means relation to value(varchar in context)

Comment: Maybe you are returning more than 1 record in your sub query?  Try running that separately, or put a TOP 1 to ensure you only get one from the sub query

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  what's your concern?  both contain dept_name; likely same datatype/size; though you don't say.  so why do you think an implicit conversion is occurring?  is ID in instructor numeric?  if so yes an implicit conversion is occurring.

Comment: @xQbert I treat dept_name as variable instead of column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question about the mechanics of SQL.

You are using a subquery in the context where a single value is being used.  Such a subquery is called a *scalar subquery*.  A scalar subquery returns one value and SQL treats this value as a single variable if it is used in an expression expecting a scalar.  The same query in the `FROM` clause would return a relation.

Such a subquery generally has two properties:

- Returns exactly 1 column (although this is relaxed on some databases)
- Returns 0 or 1 row

If the subquery returns more than one row, then you will get an error.  If it returns zero rows, then the value is `NULL`.

Whenever you are referring to more than one table in a query, I strongly recommend that you always use table aliases and qualified column names:

```
select count(s.ID)
from student s
where s.dept_name = (select i.dept_name
                     from instructor i
                     where i.ID = 14364
                    );
```

Also, if the ids are numbers, then don't use single quotes.

Comment: A column can equal varchar in SQL? What if column name is not dept-name?

Comment: I just cannot understand relation, column, and value, are they all variables like other programming languages?

Comment: @ShawnXu . . . Think of it as a convenience.  SQL automatically converts a relation with a single column and a single row into a "variable" value, if it is expecting a variable value.